# Add sum of input which is appendTo another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add result of items which I `.appendTo` another `<div>`.
I would like the total to increase every time the *item `<button>`* is clicked.
Is this possible when the result is `.appendTo` another `<div>`?

```html
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="total"></div>

<button class="menu item1">Item 1</button>
<button class="menu item2">Item 2</button>
<button class="menu item3">Item 3</button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.item1').click(function(){
       $('<div class="skill">80</div><br/>').appendTo('.item');
    });
    $('.item2').click(function(){
       $('<div class="skill">90</div><br/>').appendTo('.item');
    });
    $('.item3').click(function(){
       $('<div class="skill">100</div><br/>').appendTo('.item');
    });
});

$(".item").each(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(this).find(".skill").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
    $(this).text('Total: ' + total).appendTo(".total");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your event handlers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.item1').click(function(){

      $('<div class="skill">80</div><br/>').appendTo('.item');

      counter();
    });

    $('.item2').click(function(){

      $('<div class="skill">90</div><br/>').appendTo('.item');

      counter();              
    });
    $('.item3').click(function(){

      $('<div class="skill">100</div><br/>').appendTo('.item');

      counter();
    }); 

    var counter = function() {

        var total = 0;

        $(".skill").each(function() {

            total += +$(this).text();
        });

        $('.total').text('Total: ' + total);
    };
});

</script>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qoyk8h3v/)

Answer (score 0):

The code to calculate total needs to be inside .click function of each of the three buttons. Currently it's being called only once.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make calculation inside each button `click` handler:

No need for loops and parsing text of items if the content is static.

```
var total = 0;
$('.item1').click(function(){
    $('<div class="skill">80</div><br/>').appendTo('.item');
    $(".total").text('Total: ' + (total+=80));
});
$('.item2').click(function(){
    $('<div class="skill">90</div><br/>').appendTo('.item');
    $(".total").text('Total: ' + (total+=90));
});
$('.item3').click(function(){
    $('<div class="skill">100</div><br/>').appendTo('.item');
    $(".total").text('Total: ' + (total+=100));
});
```

[**JSfiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5kevvxk1/1/)

---

And even better (for dynamic use), is to use [`data` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). That way you can make just single `click` handler for all of the buttons.

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#"><button data-count="80" class="add menu item1">Item 1</button></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><button data-count="90" class="add menu item2">Item 2</button></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><button data-count="100" class="add menu item3">Item 3</button></a></li>
<!-- You can just put there as many items as you like, without writing extra scripts -->
```

Script (single function for all buttons):

```
var total = 0;
$('.add').click(function(){
    var count = $(this).data('count');
    $('<div class="skill">'+count+'</div><br/>').appendTo('.item');
    $(".total").text('Total: ' + (total+=count));
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/dqndhbLq/1/)

Then you can expand it even further. F.ex. adding some <kbd>remove</kbd> button for every new item, so the `total`  amount will decrease each time the item is removed. Like in this example: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2f4sj5pz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

First, make the summation functional,

```
function sumSkills() {
    var $item = $('.item'),
        $total = $('.total'),
        total = 0;
    $item.find('.skill').each(function (elm) {
        total += parseInt($(elm).text(), 10);
    });
    $total.text('Total: ' + total);
}
```

Now you can apply this code whenever you like, e.g.

```
$('.item1').click(function () {
    $('<div class="skill">80</div><br/>').appendTo('.item');
    sumSkills();
});
```